# C# Generic List Union Question

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm trying to merge 2 lists using "Union" so I get rid of duplicates. Following is the sample code:

```
public class SomeDetail
{
    public string SomeValue1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue2  { get; set; }
    public string SomeDate { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDetailComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeDetail>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<SomeDetail>.Equals(SomeDetail x, SomeDetail y)
    {
        // Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.        
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        // Check whether any of the compared objects is null.        
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        return x.SomeValue1 == y.SomeValue1 && x.SomeValue2 == y.SomeValue2;
    }
    int IEqualityComparer<SomeDetail>.GetHashCode(SomeDetail obj)
    {
        return obj.SomeValue1.GetHashCode();
    }
}

List<SomeDetail> tempList1 = new List<SomeDetail>();
List<SomeDetail> tempList2 = new List<SomeDetail>();

List<SomeDetail> detailList = tempList1.Union(tempList2, SomeDetailComparer).ToList();
```

Now the question is can I use Union and still get the record which has the latest date (using SomeDate property). The record itself can either be in tempList1 or tempList2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operation that is really suited to this purpose is an [full outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_join#Full_outer_join). The `Enumerable` class has an implementation of inner join, which you can use to find the duplicates and select whichever you prefer.

```
var duplicates = Enumerable.Join(tempList1, tempList2,  keySelector, keySelector, 
    (item1, item2) => (item1.SomeDate > item2.SomeDate) ? item1 : item2)
    .ToList();
```

`keySelector` is simply a function (could be a lambda expression) that extracts a key from an object of type `SomeDetail`. Now, to implement the full outer join, try something like this:

```
var keyComparer = (SomeDetail item) => new { Value1 = item.SomeValue1,
    Value2 = item.SomeDetail2 };
var detailList = Enumerable.Union(tempList1.Except(tempList2, equalityComparer), 
    tempList2.Except(tempList1, equalityComparer)).Union(
    Enumerable.Join(tempList1, tempList2, keyComparer, keyComparer
    (item1, item2) => (item1.SomeDate > item2.SomeDate) ? item1 : item2))
    .ToList();
```

`equalityComparer` should be an object that implements `IEqualityComparer<SomeDetail>` and effectively uses the `keyComparer` function for testing equality.

Let me know if that does the job for you.

Comment: I used a unique value in the SomeDetail class for the selector but isn't returing any records. Any help Please?

var detailList = Enumerable.Join(tempList1, tempList2,
item1 => item1.UniqueKey, item2 => item2.UniqueKey,     
(item1, item2) => (item1.SomeDate > item2.SomeDate) ? item1 : item2)    
.ToList();

Comment: @Ganesha: Have you verified that there *are* at least some items with identical UniqueKey values?

Comment: Oh! The lists could have totally diferent values. If there is a matching value then, the date has to be taken into account to decide which one will be selected

If there is no matching value then the value will still have to copied over. (just like in the case of Union)

Comment: Well in your original question you're comparing items based on the expression `x.SomeValue1 == y.SomeValue1 && x.SomeValue2 == y.SomeValue2`. This would mean you would want to select a tuple of SomeValue1 and SomeValue2 as the key. (In C#, the best option is probably to use anonymous types. I'll update my answer with the code.)

Comment: The new code with the key comparer does not return any records? Any help please?

Comment: What are your SomeValue1 and SomeValue2 properties? We're going to need a few more specifics if we're to help.

Comment: Func<UsageDetail, string> keyComparer = (UsageDetail item) => item.SiteUrl
siteUsageDetails = Enumerable.Join(siteUsageDetails, tempUsageDetails, keyComparer, keyComparer,
                                (item1, item2) => (Convert.ToDateTime(item1.LastActivityDate) > Convert.ToDateTime(item2.LastActivityDate)) ? item1 : item2)
                                .ToList();

This is exactly what I am  trying to accomplish

Comment: @Ganesha: Sorry, it seems I was giving you code for the wrong type of join! You actually want a *full outer join*. See my updated answer and check if that does the job.

Comment: Like this idea actually but this one does not return, probably goes into an infinite loop

Comment: Sorry, my problem. The problem was with the equality comparer. Now it seems to be working. I will have to take a closer look. Thanks

Comment: Kind of getting close. When I do a merge of those Lists, the behavior is kind of random (i.e.) I see different dates each time I run

Comment: @Ganesha: Are you sure you're not just seeing the same set, but reordered each time you run the code?

Comment: I'm actually seeing different output everytime and is not consistent

Comment: @Ganesha: Not sure what to suggest now, really. Have you verified that your data sources (tempList1 and tempList2) are identical on each run?

Comment: Yes, the lists have the same data. The merged results are perfect too (i.e.) they are unique. It's just that the dates vary everytime I run. I need the record with the latest date to show up in the final merged list

Comment: @Ganesha: Heh, that was a bit of a battle! Glad it's working now though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to be able to tell Union how to pick which one of the duplicates to use.  I don't know of a way to do that other than writing your own Union.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot with the standard `Union` method, but you can create an extension method `Union` for `List<SomeDetail>` with this special handling and this method will be used because the signature fits better.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use HashSet<T>?

```
List<SomeDetail> tempList1 = new List<SomeDetail>();
List<SomeDetail> tempList2 = new List<SomeDetail>();

HashSet<SomeDetail> hs = new HashSet<SomeDetail>(new SomeDetailComparer());

hs.UnionWith(tempList1);
hs.UnionWith(tempList2);

List<SomeDetail> detailList = hs.ToList();
```

Comment: This would work if I need unique records. I have an additional requirement where on merge I need the record which has the latest date between the 2 lists.

Answer (score 0):

Merge generic lists

```
    public static List<T> MergeListCollections<T>(List<T> firstList, List<T> secondList)
    {
        List<T> merged = new List<T>(firstList);
        merged.AddRange(secondList);
        return merged;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this will eliminate duplicates, which was specified in the question.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
list1.RemoveAll(p => list2.Any(z => z.SomeValue1 == p.SomeValue1 &&
                               z => z.SomeValue2 == p.SomeValue1 &&
                               z => z.SomeDate == p.SomeDate));
var list3 =  list2.Concat<SomeDetail>(list1).ToList();
```