# How to merge similar IList<T> objects in C# asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a class:

```
public class Data {

 public Ilist<Prod> Product;

 public Data() {}
  public Data(List<Prod> prod)
  {
      this.Product = prod
  }
}
```

No I try to use this class in my controller to bind values to my model

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
  {
     data.Prod =  GetProductByUser(username); // this is the base user

     IList<AdditionalUsers> add_usrs = GetAddUsersForBaseUsers(username);

     // now to the data.prod (product list I need to add the prod for the base users
     //so I loop through the add users and try to get the products for each base use

     for(AdditionalUsers aid in add_usrs)
     {
            //now data.prod has products for base users. So now I need to add produts 
            //for add users using same method

     } 

}
```

Now in the for loop  I need to call the same method   GetAddUsersForBaseUsers(username); to add product for all the additional users and add it to the  data.Product list. How will I be able to do this?

Comment: I wonder how many others end up thinking ...what?

Comment: maybe its just me.. but I have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: btw,.. if you spell "additional" correctly in one line of code - how is it misspelled in the very next line of code?

Comment: @Adam: TO make this simple I just want to know how do we merge to List<prod> objects? .

Comment: @Pinu: Can you define "merge"?  Copy elements from one list to another?

Comment: Do you need to remove duplicates?

Comment: This question provides a few options:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849545/c-generic-list-union-question

Comment: Why won't the solution James provided below work with Concat? It seems easy and clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your constructor is wrong. You're trying to set data.Prop where Prop is a type, not a public field/property.
Also, where are you declaring your *data* variable?

You could use the following instead:
`Data data = new Data(GetProductByUser(username));`

Make your Product field as a publicly accessible property as well. 
To do this, replace
`public Ilist<Prod> Product;`
with `public IList<Prod> Product { get; set;}`

To Add the users, you can use the following.

```
foreach(AdditionalUsers aid in add_usrs)
{
   //add users
   data.Product.Add(aid);
}
```

Alternatively you can just replace the property *Product* which is of type `IList` with a `List` and then do the following:
`data.Product.AddRange(add_usrs);`

Comment: it's giving me an build error saying "cannot convert System.Collection.Generics.IList<Prod> to  Prod

Comment: Oh I thought `GetProductByUser(username)` returns an IList<Prod>. My bad. Use `Data data = new Data(new List<Prod> {GetProductByUser(username)});`

Comment: Also, since it represents a list of *Prod*, rename your property to *Products*. It's more readable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Concat function, like this:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
List<int> lst2 = new List<int>();
List<int> lst3 = new List<int>();

lst.Concat(lst2).Concat(lst3);
```

Comment: weird. I would think this would be the simplest solution here in this sea of prior 'interesting' code

Comment: I think the problem is that you end up with an IEnumerable not an IList.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.Prod = GetProductByUser(username);
IList<AdditionalUsers> add_usrs = GetAddUsersForBaseUsers(username);
List<List<Prod>> productsForAdditional = new List<List<Prod>>();
foreach(AdditionalUsers aid in add_usrs)
{
  //get all of those lists.
  productsForAdditional.Add(GetProductByUser(aid.UserName);
}
//add all of the items from all of those lists to the primary list
data.Prod.AddRange(productsForAdditional.SelectMany(list => list));
```